# If int value equal to x replace with a string

Tags: c#, getter-setter

I am storing a int in  `schadstoffklasse` so when calling the Car object like so (last int in brackets) :  
 `PKW Kaefer = new PKW("VW", "Käfer", "K-GS-01", 1965, 9999, 1000, 30, 1);`

I can either say 0, 1, 2. 
Now when i write this `Console.WriteLine(Kaefer.Schadstoffklasse)`
to the console it obiously outputs 1 in this case.

I do want it to not say 1 i want for example....

`0 = foo`
`1 = bar`
`2 = foobar`

So it outputs to the console a string.

Here is what i have tried, which does not work.

```
private int schadstoffklasse;

    public int Schadstoffklasse
    {
        get
        {
            return schadstoffklasse;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == 0)
            {
                string foo = value.ToString();
                foo = "BLABLALBA";

            }

            schadstoffklasse = value;
        }
    }
```

Thank you for having patience with a beginner

Comment: do you get an error message?

Comment: No, should i get any error message ?

Comment: if you want the value of your string, you should not to create your string within the property.

Comment: You could override `ToString` in your class (with, possibly, some overloads) to return whatever value you want when you write `MyBaseClass.ToString()`. Or use a method getter: `MyClass.GetSchadstoffklasse()` which returns the desired string representation of the value. Many other ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have a property return mixed types. Your property of `Schadstoffklasse` is an `int`, therefore it can only ever return an `int` never a string.

There are a variety of different ways to accomplish this though, but without knowing more of how you are using this it'd be impossible to say which one you should do. I'd recommend either another property that has no setter and the getter looks at the other property, reads it's value and returns the string that you want or a method that does the same.

To expand on my suggestion:

```
public enum SchadstofklasseStrings
{
    foo = 0,
    bar = 1,
    foobar = 2
}

public int Schadstoffklasse { get; set; }
public string SchadstoffklasseToString { 
{
    get
    {
        var stringValue = (SchadstofklasseStrings) Schadstoffklasse;
        return stringValue.ToString();
     }
}
```

Also, sorry for mutilating the German.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the type of a variable from int to string .
in this case i would create an array

```
["foo","bar","foobar"]
```

and use value of `schadstoffklasse` as an index

```
Console.WriteLine(Kaefer.myArray[Schadstoffklasse]);
```

Comment: Seems fragile to keep track of indexing like that. If you're going to make a hardcoded list of things it could be, I'd prefer an enum.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
private int schadstoffklasse;
public object Schadstoffklasse
    {
        get
        {
         if(this.schadstoffklasse==0)
             return "foo";
         if(this.schadstoffklasse==1)
             return "bar";
         if(this.schadstoffklasse==2)
             return "foobar";
         return "N/A";
        }
        set
        {
            this.schadstoffklasse=(int)value;
        }
    }
```

> Note: The explain from user @gilliduck is useful. Consider this just
>   as a situational workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I find `enum` helpful in situations like this since it is a collection of named integers. This is one example of how I might handle it.

```
void Main()
{
    var Kaefer = new PKW("VW", "Käfer", "K-GS-01", 1965, 9999, 1000, 30, Schadstoffklassen.Bar);
    Console.WriteLine(Enum.GetName(typeof(Schadstoffklassen), Kaefer.Schadstoffklasse));
    // Output: Bar
}

public class PKW
{
    private Schadstoffklassen schadstoffklasse;

    public PKW(string v1, string v2, string v3, int v4, int v5, int v6, int v7, Schadstoffklassen _schadstoffklasse) {
        schadstoffklasse = _schadstoffklasse;
    }

    public Schadstoffklassen Schadstoffklasse
    {
        get { return schadstoffklasse; }
        set { schadstoffklasse = value; }
    }
}

public enum Schadstoffklassen {
    Foo = 0,
    Bar = 1,
    FooBar = 2
}
```